# What does cynical actually mean?

Tags: meaning

The dictionary definition of cynical is:

> believing that people are motivated purely by self-interest; distrustful of human sincerity or integrity

However, there is an additional bullet point under this definition that says:

> contemptuous; mocking

I fail to understand how these two definitions are related. My personal understanding is that cynicism is being skeptical of another person's motives. "Mocking; contemptuous" seems to suggest a more attacking tone. To me, this definition suggests that cynical and contemptuous can be used interchangeably, which I do not think is correct from the examples I have seen, as well as from daily interactions.

Definitions are from [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=cynical).

Edit: Perhaps a cynical attitude is a subset of contemptuous attitudes?

Comment: Hi Skyzx, please cite your sources.

Comment: Perhaps the example provided by Google for *contemptuous* will shed some light: "she was intolerant and contemptuous of the majority of the human race."

Comment: @livresque It’s that thing that comes up when you search “define <word>” on google, not sure what to call that

Comment: You should attribute "Oxford Languages" (look closely at the top of the widget to see the source).

Comment: If you thought people were solely motivated by self-interest, wouldn't you have a low opinion of them, maybe even view them with contempt?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cynical) adds a third sense: '3.  showing contempt for accepted standards of behaviour, especially of honesty or morality' As in 'a cynical foul'.  And later, arguably a fourth. Words come to be used in different ways (consider 'gay'; 'wicked'), the connections between such usages possibly being hard to see.  Senses may to a smaller or larger (contranyms) degree be contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Collins provides a better definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cynical) of this sense of the word:

> sarcastic, sneering, etc.

Cynicism (in the modern sense) refers not just to a way of thinking, but also to a way of *talking,* one that is bitter, caustic, and often sarcastic. This tone is typically used when describing a harsh, negative view of the world, e.g. when suggesting that others are generally motivated by self-interest alone.

In this way the two senses of the word are related: the "contemptuous" tone is the tone often used when expressing a skeptical view of others' motives.

Answer (score 0):

The first defines their *Belief* system in broad terms. The other bullet point describes how they *Behave* toward people as a result of these beliefs.

Comment: That might be an explanation of how the two meanings are related, but I don't think that a cynic necessarily behaves contemptuously towards other people.

Answer (score 0):

If you **describe** someone as cynical, this is when you apply the first definition: believing people are selfish.

But, if you describe an **action** as cynical, like a cynical look, then it's used as an adjective. This is where you can  apply it as being sarcastic.